# How to Handle Physical Camera Button on Android Device

Tags: android, camera

I have a Droid X, which has a physical camera button. I am using the example used here: http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

The app sort-of works. The on-screen button captures and displays the preview image. But if I push the physical camera button, the app crashes.

How should I handle this, and more importantly - is this going to cause problems across different devices that do / do not have physical buttons?

Comment: "But if I push the physical camera button, the app crashes." -- use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override `onKeyDown` in your `Activity`

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        switch(keyCode)
        {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA:
           // handle the event here
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am assuming that this will do nothing if the phone does not have a physical button?

Comment: yes, it would be called whenever a button is pressed. But then `case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CAMERA` will not be executed and the code will be returned to the super class `Activity`